# HTML5 Geolocation not working on Safari - Mac OS/ iOS

Tags: html, safari, geolocation

HTML5 Geolocation works fine on Chrome, FF, Edge, IE and Safari 5 for Windows.
However, it does not work on Safari for Mac OS and iOS. Tried on El Capitan and Sierra and iOS 10.
Can the cause be related to a particular Safari version?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this over https?  If not some newer webkit browsers will restrict geolocation this over http.  You don't say what version of chrome you're using, so offering this up as a potential reason.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5 geolocation is no longer supported over http**

What version of safari are you using? I am using Safari Version 9.1.2 on El Capitan version 10.11.6. And geolocation is working properly for me over https.
I think the problem is either that you are not using Geolocation over https OR
You are using a version of safari that doesn't suppert HTML5 Geolocation.